# What traces of an application can apt-get purge still leave behind?

Tags: linux, apt-get

I noticed that `apt-get purge` doesn't always clean every trace of an installation.

As a concrete example, I'm trying to remove mailman (installed by `apt-get install mailman`).
Now, I tried to remove every(!) trace of this installation by `apt-get purge mailman`.

`find / -name '*mailman*'` reveals that there is still some stuff from mailman around:

```
/run/mailman
/var/cache/apt/archives/mailman_1%3a2.1.16-2_amd64.deb
/var/spool/postfix/private/mailman
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mailmanctl
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/mailman.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/mailman.mo
```

Also, the installation created an additional user "list" and  a group "list" that I'm quite sure wasn't there before.

So, I was wondering how thorough `apt-get purge` is? In other words, in what way might `apt-get install X; apt-get purge X;` change my system? And are there more thorough methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a package, the files generated by the build process are registered. When you uninstall a package, these files will be removed (`remove` keeps config files, `purge` removes them, too).

If a program itself generates files, the package manager usually doesn't know about this, and won't touch these files.

Also, third party addons, suggested packages or dependencies may create files which do not belong to the removed/purged package, even if they don't make any sense without it.

To find out to which package a file belongs, use apt-file:

```
apt-file search /path/to/file
```

You may need to install apt-file and update its database:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file && sudo apt-file update
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`apt-get --purge remove PACKAGE` instead of  `apt-get purge`

`apt-get --purge remove mailman`

AND this will remove the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get autoremove mailman
```